# Find the translation between two origins based on the camera positions

Tags: python, opencv, camera, opencv-solvepnp

I have determined the camera position based on two origins in the field of view of the camera. Let's say origin 1 is located at (140,200) and origin 2 is located at (70,180).

Following are the camera positions with respect to origin 1 and origin 2.

```
X1,Y1,Z1,X2,Y2,Z2 = 0.8361721744324895,-0.5131803297263005,1.3708440418732257,0.09985411281689659,0.3329507542440152,1.342809058827907
```

whereas the (X1, Y1, Z1) are the camera position with respect to the origin 1 while (X2, Y2, Z2) is the camera position with respect to the origin 2.

I have used the following code to compute the translation between both origins.

```
dist = math.sqrt((X1-X2) ** 2 + (Y1-Y2) **2 + (Z1-Z2)**2)
```

However, the value is a scalar and not a vector (XYZ) value of the translation between the origins based on their respective camera positions. How can I get the XYZ distances?

Comment: I am not sure I have understood your question, but I'm guessing that the translation vector between two points `(x1, y1, z1)` and `(x2, y2, z2)` is just `(x2-x1, y2-y1, z2-z1)`

Comment: Isn't it the translation vector between the two camera positions and not the object positions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a third origin, apart from your two origins.

With respect to this third origin, let the position vectors of the camera, first origin, and second origin be `r_c`, `r_1`, and `r_2`, respectively.

With respect to the first origin, let the position vector of the camera be `r_c_1`

With respect to the second origin, let the position vector of the camera be `r_c_2`

Using `--` as the symbol for vector subtraction, we have:

`r_c_1 = r_c -- r_1`

`r_c_2 = r_c -- r_2`

From the above two equations, subtracting one equation from the other, we get:

`r_c_2 -- r_c_1 = (r_c -- r_2) -- (r_c -- r_1)`

which, on simplifying, gives:

`r_c_2 -- r_c_1 = r_1 -- r_2`

In the above equation, the RHS is **what you want** (the translation vector between the two origins). The LHS is the vector-subtraction between the camera positions under the two origins.

So, if  the vectors are represented in 3-tuple notation, let `r_c_1` and `r_c_2` be `(x1, y1, z1)`, and `(x2, y2, z2)`, respectively. Then, from the above equation, the require "origin-translation-vector" will `(x2-x1, y2-y1, z2-z1)`